Add ssh key to Xcode cloud to access bitbucket private repositories
I have one project and in which I have multiple private cocoa pods. i hosted all pods in my private git repository.
I have local pod specs repository which have multiple pod specs for different pods. all pods are accessible using SSH only.
I want to setup iOS app build pipeline to Xcode Cloud. I am successfully able to clone main pod specs repository by adding secondary repository.
while starting to the pod install, cocoa pod starting to clone pod from bitbucket and at that time its failing due to access.
I have around 50 private pods and based on the project requirement usage of number of pods different so I can not keep giving access to private pod repository one by one,
I am thinking to generate one ssh key for Xcode cloud and every time build start I install that ssh key to Xcode cloud machine which may help to get rid of granting access.
I have very limited knowledge of operating systems so please help.
